# php call a variable from another function from another file and pass it to an array

Tags: php

I've a.php file

It has 4 functions. Each function has a variable

function1 has $var1
function2 has $var2
function3 has $var3
function4 has $var4

I've set all four variables as global

I've another file b.php

I want to call those 4 variables from a.php and set them on array in b.php

What I did is this (but it didn't work) :

I've added

```
include ('a.php file path');
$myArray = array($var1,$var2,$var3,$var4);
```

Comment: Show the contents of `a.php`

Comment: You should post your code instead of trying to explain it.

Comment: make sure you are setting variables global in functions also

Comment: Are variables $var1, $var2, $var3, $var declared outside those functions or only inside functions with keyword `global` ? See example #1 in PHP manual [how to use global](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: Feel no fear constructing longer sentences. We are used to it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [global keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).  Here are the things to remember about variable scope:

- variables declared within a class or function are automatically scoped to that class or function.
- variable declared outside any class or function are global by default.
- if you want to use a global variable within a function, you have to use the global keyword so PHP knows you mean to use the global, and not some similarly-named local.

Here is an example, using just $var1.  The other variables would use the same technique.

## b.php

```
$var1 = "blah";
```

## a.php

```
// including b.php causes the global $var1 to be defined
include "b.php";

// outside of any class or function, $var1 refers to the global
echo ($var1 . "\n");  // prints "blah"

function x() {
    $var1;  // This is a local variable, not the global one.

    // within this function, $var1 has not been defined, so you get a blank
    // (or perhaps a Notice depending on your log settings) when you try
    // to print it out.
    echo ($var1."\n"); 
}

function y() {
    // This is how you tell PHP you wish to use a global variable from
    // inside a function.
    global $var1;

    echo ($var1."\n");
}

x();
y();
```

Comment: This is what I did and it didn't work

I tried to troubleshoot the problem, so started to delete code from a.php to figure out where the problem is.

I ended up with an a.php file with only, and I mean only, this code:

<?php
global $x = 1;
?>

No functions, no any thing else. And it didn't work!

Now, b.php file, is actually this code for graph:
http://jpgraph.net/features/src/show-example.php?target=new_line1.php

I'm trying to pull out the array values from a.php as variables

I'm wondering now if that code might not accept "include" for some reason?

Comment: You're using the global keyword wrong.  Please see my updates to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it doing this:

I merged a.php with b.php, so that b.php file would not need en extra "include" command, which I think it never work with jpgrah

After that, I just called the variables from inside the functions like this:

```
function1($var1);
function2($var2);
function3($var3);
function4($var4);
```

Then set the values inside the `array($var1,$var2,$var3,$var4);`

And that worked!

Thank you